# Local Storage remove Item and remove list

Tags: javascript

I am at the end of my Project. I have problem with add favorites        and to remove item from local storage. It works to delete it from html but when you refresh the page, items are again here. Also remove whole favorites its not working. I hope that someone see my mistake

```
   I try to remove whole list with function but its also not working.

    <body>
    <main>
   <h1>Your Favourite Recipes</h1>
<p>These are your favourite recipes that we have saved for you.</p>
  <button id="probam" type="button" 
 name="button" onclick="deleteListe()">brisi</button>
  <p id="fav"></p>

  <script>
   let list = localStorage.getItem('favorites');
   list = list ? list.split(',') : [];
   var ll = [];
   ll = list;

   var output = document.createElement('ul');
   output.setAttribute('id', 'list')


   for (let i = 0; i < ll.length; i++) {
       var it = document.createElement('li');
       var bt = document.createElement('button');
       bt.innerHTML = ('Delete');
       bt.setAttribute('class', 'delete')

       it.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ll[i]));
       it.appendChild(bt);
       output.appendChild(it);
   }

   document.getElementById('fav').appendChild(output);

   var del = document.getElementsByClassName('delete');

   for (let j = 0; j < del.length; j++) {
       del[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
           // console.log((del[j].parentNode).parentNode);
           (del[j].parentNode).parentNode.removeChild(del[j].parentNode);
       })
   }
   function deleteListe() {
  localStorage.removeItem("favorites");
   }
    </script>
  <button type="button" name="button"></button>
  <a  href="index.html" class='vido'>Home</a>
  </main>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I little change your code, and i added for all button required functions

```
    <h1>Your Favourite Recipes</h1>
    <p>These are your favourite recipes that we have saved for you.</p>
    <button id="probam" type="button" name="button" onclick="deleteListe()">brisi</button>
    <p id="fav"></p>
    <script>
    function deleteListe() {
        localStorage.removeItem("favorites");
    }

    function deleteElement(element) {
        const newFavorites = (localStorage.getItem('favorites')||"").replace(element,"");
        localStorage.setItem("favorites",newFavorites.split(",").filter(Boolean).join(","));
        setTimeout(()=>{
          localStorage.getItem('favorites')
          location.reload();
        },10);
    }

    let list = (localStorage.getItem('favorites')||"").split(",").filter(Boolean);


   var output = document.createElement('ul');
   output.setAttribute('id', 'list')

   list.forEach((el)=>{
       var it = document.createElement('li');
       var bt = document.createElement('button');
       bt.innerHTML = ('Delete');
       bt.setAttribute('class', 'delete');
       bt.setAttribute('title', el);
       it.appendChild(document.createTextNode(el));
       it.appendChild(bt);
       output.appendChild(it);
   });  

   document.getElementById('fav').appendChild(output);

   var del = document.getElementsByClassName('delete');

   for (let j = 0; j < del.length; j++) {
       del[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
            deleteElement(this.getAttribute('title'));
           (this.parentNode).parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
       })
   }

    </script>
    <button type="button" name="button"></button>
    <a href="index.html" class='vido'>Home</a>
```

Comment: Thanx so much, its working perfect, its just problem at the end when i delete all of items, always is left one Dot from list and one button delete :) and i cant figure it out ;(

Comment: i fixed this, you can check